# opensourcemano: Authorization error when Instantiating Network Service in OSM Launchpad

Tags: open-source

While instantiating the Network Service through OSM Launch Pad. I am receiving the error:

```
Instantiation of NS  : failed
VIM Exception vimconnUnexpectedResponse AuthorizationFailure: Authorization Failed: Unable to establish connection to http://<ip address>:5000/v2.0/tokens. (True, ' Rollback successful.')
```

Not sure how can I correct this. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same "Authorization Failed" message when I tried to use OSM to launch a service on OpenStack Mitaka.  The error log in OpenStack said "Could not find domain:default".

After the OSM2 release, I changed to OpenStack Newton, and this solved the problem.